# Permission denied running my own program on Linux?

Tags: opengl, permission-denied, ubuntu-9.04

I have Ubuntu 9.4. I've built the program, some basic OpenGL. The program just makes a rotating square. Then run it and:

```
sh: /blabla permission denied.
```

And an empty `main` doesn't work:

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

How can I make that disappear?

Comment: What are the permissions on the program's file?

Comment: What exactly is the command you are entering?

Comment: run button in codeblocks, ./test after I do cd ... and double click. None of them work

Comment: @KdgDev, advising people to make programs world-writable is horrid advice: It means anyone with access to any part of their machine, even the `nobody` user that's supposed to have no access privileges at all, can modify the script to add potentially-malicious content. `750` is more than sufficient for a script one wishes to run oneself, or `755` for world-readability and executability.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Indeed. Good lord, I left that comment in June 2009. That's over 6 years ago. I think at that point I had maybe once installed Ubuntu via Wubi(fun stuff, Wubi, sad it's not getting maintenance anymore). Having worked with Ubuntu and other distro's in a professional capacity since then, I no longer feel it's funny to say "777 the file" as I did back then. That's like saying "just merge develop in to the hotfix branch, what's the worse that could happen". That actually happened to me once, holy sh*t that gave me cold sweat.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem and it appeared that my partition was mounted as noexec
cat /etc/mtab

When I configured options in /etc/fstab I wrote exec,user but it appears that "user" option by default sets up "noexec". When I changed the order of these two to user,exec everything went back to normal!

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 7):

How are you compiling it? Can you post the makefile? If you run

```
chmod +x myPorgram
./myProgram
```

something changes?

Comment: I'm compiling with codeblocks. And I tried that nothing, tried with sudo and still nothing.

Answer (score 5):

Check the mountpoint to see if it's mounted as noexec by running "mount"

Answer (score 2):

I use CodeBlocks on Ubuntu and have had this exact problem MANY times. 
what KermiDT said is exactly the solution (if i had enough rep points, i would have voted it up)
The "user" option by default sets up "noexec".
so in /etc/fstab just add ,exec after user.
i.e. mine looks like this:
`/dev/sda6                                  /media/DATA  vfat  uid=kenny,gid=kenny,users,user,exec  0  0` 
Though, the spacingis a bit off... but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of questions:

1. Are the permissions set correctly on the file?
2. Is the path to any interpreter set correctly?

Comment: I don't know about those things... it only happens on the new computer

I had same compilaer same ubuntu and there it just runs

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the above mentioned chmod +x file, another problem might be a missing library. To check the required libraries, use ldd:

```
$ ldd /bin/sh
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffb43fe000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc4abe11000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc4ac183000)
```

If one of these lines shows a missing library, you'll know what needs to be installed before you can run your program.

Another possibility is if your program is a script (shell, perl, python or other text-based program). The first line looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

If that file cannot be found, you'll get a permission denied error.

Comment: not a dynamic executable hmmm but in the permission page the executable option is marked and also i did the chmod +x on it... Though I doubt there are extra libraries needed for int main(){}

Comment: "Not a dynamic executable" ?
Can you show us how you are compiling your program ?
Please also do a "file yourexefile", this should say something like
      $ file /bin/bash
     /bin/bash: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped

Regarding the extra libraries, having just main(){} doesn't mean anything, if it was compiled with the opengl libs, they'll be required to run the program.

Comment: I'm hitting the build button in codeblocks... that worked on the other computer untill now, I also compiled without any libraries linked and it didn't run. The file test : test: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, not stripped

Answer (score 1):

You also get this problem when trying to execute 32-bit apps on a 64-bit system.  Execute:

```
a. file (executable name)
b. uname -a
```

and check that both are either "i386" or "amd64".

If they are not the same, have a look at [this article](http://www.markusbe.com/2009/09/about-running-32-bit-programs-on-64-bit-ubuntu-and-shared-libraries/#comment-279):

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the command with [`strace`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) to trace the successful system calls it makes and where it stops.

This is how you might launch it,

```
strace ./blabla
```

Do you get a "permission denied" error or something like "exec format error"? With **`chmod +rx`** on the file you should not hit "permission denied".

Answer (score 0):

You should also make sure that your username is in the video group.  Check the /etc/group and make sure that your username appears on the "video" line.